# Alternative methods for logistic regression

Tags: logistic, binary-data, predictor, validity

Usually the condition of the validity of a logistic regression is to have 10 events per predictor.

In our model the binary outcome variable (1 if Healthy aging ; 0 otherwise) has a frequency of healthy aging for around 1000 observations (37% of the sample).

Also there are 13 predictor variables, so the assumption of having 10 events per variable is widely satisfied.

But the question is the frequency of 37%.

Edited:

In this logistic regression model, we can't interpret odds-ratios as relative risks due to high event rate. What other regression methods can we use to model a binary outcome?

Comment: I often find that 20 events per predictor are required.  But this is oversimplified because you need at least 96 observations just to estimate the intercept.  I don't understand why you think a proportion of 0.37 for $Y=1$ could be a problem.  And isn't healthy aging a continuous concept?  If you used any dichotomization to arrive at $Y$ you'll get an inappropriate analysis.

Comment: Thank you Dr. Harrell. In this context the variable for healthy aging was created using several criteria on healthy aging components, such as absence of cancer-diabetes-cardiovascular disease ; overall cognitive functioning; depressive symptoms; quality of life, etc. As far as i know there was no dichotomization. I was told to use a poisson regression as an alternative to the logistic model, due to the high event rate. For me, it's not really necessary to use a Poisson model here.

Comment: Poisson models are for count data for $Y$.  Your $Y$ dichotomized several continuous variables.  Although it's challenging to put together multiple outcomes into one variable, it's worth doing because binary $Y$ has minimal information/minimum power.

Comment: Did all the subjects die already or do you have aome right- and/or left-censoring here?

Comment: @Björn Our sample consisted of people with no misssing values for baseline data. For example BMI at baseline had no missing values but after 6 year of follow up, 9% of information was missing for this variable. Anyway, we are mainly interested in analysing the variation of BMI over healthy aging and consider a selected sample (about 3000 observations) of people who survived at the end of the follow-up.

Comment: My point was the selection bias of looking at it that way, when some may have becone unhealthy but you do not know (losses to follow-up) and some may yet do so (i.e. after the end of follow-up). Why only look at those alive? Presumably all will die eventually,  what is the effect on your inference of looking at only those alive?

Comment: What do you mean by using Poisson regression? Is your outcome not just a yes/no, but rather a 0,1,2,3,4...? Or do you mean approximating the binomial distribution for extremely low rates and large risk sets by a Poisson distribution? Or do you mean using a Poisson regression likelihood with a follow-up offset to fit an exponential time-to-event model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In epidemiology, sometimes we are interested in calculating RRs than ORs. When the rare disease assumption is not valid (i.e. event rate is more than 10%) we cannot interprete odds-ratios as relative risks in logistic regression.

In order to calculate risks in this case, we used modified Poisson regression (cf. reference below) with robust error variance.

**References:**

1. Guangyong Zou, **A Modified Poisson Regression Approach to Prospective Studies with Binary Data**, Am. J. Epidemiol. (2004) 159 (7): 702-706 doi:10.1093/aje/kwh090
2. **How can I estimate relative risk in SAS using proc genmod for common outcomes in cohort studies?** Introduction to SAS.  UCLA: Statistical Consulting Group. 
   from http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/sas/notes2/.